# Mathematics Online Lectures

Tags: soft-question, self-learning

I've done some research on the internet and on various platforms (Coursera, Udacity, ...) but I've found it very hard to find free online lectures in math past the level of introductory calculus/linear algebra. I know MIT has some resources but does anyone have gold mines they'd be willing to share?

I'm specifically looking for fundamentals like real and complex analysis, abstract algebra, topology, set theory, logic etc.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Although I disagree with Nj Wildberger's realist and finitistic views, his [undergraduate course on algebraic topology](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kdpbfOzkJzI) was a good watch.  Just ignore all of his insisting that we can only use rational numbers and allow for all real numbers as well.

Comment: Looks really good, thanks! That's a really useful resource

Comment: Im sorry if this comment is out of the question but, why dont read books directly? In my experience in any kind of theoretical learning and study there is no better master than a book.

Comment: No worries that's a valid point! I actually have always learned on my own with books but sometimes I think lectures can be a nice complement and it can also be a bit of a lazy way to learn when I'm tired

Comment: Coursera has a complex analysis course. https://www.coursera.org/learn/complex-analysis

Comment: Yes I saw that actually! It just made me a little sad that it was one of the only real math courses I could find on there... I also saw a small number of ones by the EPFL (in French) which seemed interesting.